# Package php7.2-mbstring missing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, php, php7

I am trying to find a way to install `php7.2-mbstring` into Ubuntu 18.04, but I can't find find it. `sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring` responds with not finding it. According to the [Cannonical](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2-mbstring) and the [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.2-mbstring) site, this packet exists though.

Is there any special thing to do to get this package?

Comment: Did you enable the universe repository? Enable it by: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`

Comment: @jdtech That was it! Installed the package. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: anything else you needed to do? I got issues on 18.04.1 https://askubuntu.com/q/1062160/37213

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling the universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

helped me installing (php7.1-mbstring):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

Thanks for jdtech and Ubuntu